# In my wp site the sitemap is getting fetched but the other sitemaps in that sitemap are not getting fetched

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

Sitemap structure:-

1. Post-sitemap.xml.        Not Fetch
2. Category-sitemap.xml     Not Fetch

Comment: Can you share URL here?